# Problem occured when deploying app engine project

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I am using Eclipse to develop an app engine application and when I want to deploy the app I obtain this error :

```
'Deploying APP_NAME to Google' has encountered a problem
 An internal error occured during "Deploying APP_NAME to Google"
```

Details are :

```
An internal error occurred during: "Deploying APP_NAME to Google".
Received IOException parsing the input stream for /home/michael/workspace/APP_NAME/war/WEB-INF/web.xml
```

Any idea how to fix this problem?

Thank you for your help.

**EDIT**

What's strange is that there isn't an error everytime I deploy the app.

web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app
PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
"http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app>

<!-- Servlets -->

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>deleteAllUniversityServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.APP_NAME.api.DeleteAllUniversities</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>deleteAllCountryServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.APP_NAME.api.DeleteAllCountries</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>deleteAllCitiesServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.APP_NAME.api.DeleteAllCities</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>addUniversity</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.APP_NAME.api.AddUniversity</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>addCity</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.APP_NAME.api.AddCity</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>addCountry</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.APP_NAME.api.AddCountry</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>addGDP</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.APP_NAME.api.AddGDP</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>addHPC</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.APP_NAME.api.AddHPC</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>addRanking</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.APP_NAME.api.AddRanking</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>greetServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.APP_NAME.server.GreetingServiceImpl</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>serverSearchServiceImpl</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.APP_NAME.server.ServerSearchServiceImpl</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>serverChartServiceImpl</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.APP_NAME.server.ServerChartServiceImpl</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>serverCoordServiceImpl</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.APP_NAME.server.ServerCoordServiceImpl</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>serverDataServiceImpl</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.APP_NAME.server.ServerDataServiceImpl</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>serverCityServiceImpl</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.APP_NAME.server.ServerCityServiceImpl</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<!-- Servlet-mappings -->

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>addUniversity</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/addUniversity</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>addCity</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/addCity</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>addCountry</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/addCountry</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>addGDP</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/addGDP</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>addHPC</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/addHPC</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>addRanking</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/addRanking</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>deleteAllCitiesServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/deleteAllCities</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>deleteAllUniversityServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/deleteAllUniversities</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>deleteAllCountryServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/deleteAllCountries</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>greetServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/APP_NAME/greet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>serverSearchServiceImpl</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/APP_NAME/serverSearch</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>serverChartServiceImpl</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/APP_NAME/serverChart</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>serverCoordServiceImpl</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/APP_NAME/serverCoord</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>serverDataServiceImpl</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/APP_NAME/serverData</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>serverCityServiceImpl</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/APP_NAME/serverCity</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Default page to serve -->
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>APP_NAME.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

**EDIT 2**

In fact when I obtain an error, there are errors in the web.xml file that appear :

```
Multiple annotations found at this line :
- Attribute "version" must be declared for element type "web-app".
- Attribute "xmlns" must be declared for element type "web-app".
```

but now, after correction, the beginning of my file look like followings :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="2.5">

    <!-- Servlets -->

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>deleteAllUniversityServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.APP_NAME.api.DeleteAllUniversities</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

        ...
```

I don't understand what's wrong...

**EDIT 3**

The problem seems to come from the DOCTYPE because when I put the DOCTYPE as a comment the application deploys correctly.

Comment: is there more to the stack trace?

Comment: There's nothing except this error...

Answer (score 0):

You are not closing the `<web-app>` node.
Try with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
"-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
"http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="2.5">
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>deleteAllUniversityServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.APP_NAME.api.DeleteAllUniversities</servlet-class>
 </servlet>

 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>deleteAllCountryServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.APP_NAME.api.DeleteAllCountries</servlet-class>
 </servlet>

 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>deleteAllCitiesServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.APP_NAME.api.DeleteAllCities</servlet-class>
 </servlet>

 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>addUniversity</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.APP_NAME.api.AddUniversity</servlet-class>
 </servlet>

 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>addCity</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.APP_NAME.api.AddCity</servlet-class>
 </servlet>

</web-app>
```

Comment: I change <web-app> to <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="2.5"> but the application deploys without error once on two...

Comment: I have corrected the element <web-app> to <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="2.5"> but there's some errors like noticed in my **EDIT 2**.